# Discord Bot (Python) Trouble with Inputs

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote a bot for a school thing, I want people who own the discord to be able to add things to the FAQ list, which I am storing in JSON.

Currently I have it as such:

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['faqadd'])
async def addfaq(ctx, question = None, *, answer = None):
```

However the problem with this is that when a person add to it as such:

```
.faqadd This is a question? This is an answer.
```

The bot will only use "This" for the question and "is a question? This is an answer." will be the answer.
Is there an easy way to just simply take in two groups of strings or should I just split it up by the question mark?

Comment: There's no good way to do it with just the argument metadata, I would just take a single string and split on "?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `discord.ext.command` interface is set up such that you have two options. One is to use positional arguments and require the user to place quotes around the arguments.

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['faqadd'])
async def addfaq(ctx, question = None, answer = None):
```

Then the user types

```
.faqadd "This is a question?" "This is an answer."
```

The other, as you've already noticed, is to take a single keyword-only argument and do the parsing yourself.

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['faqadd'])
async def addfaq(ctx, *, arg = None):
```

Answer (score 1):

discord.py is splitting your message content from space after clearing command and prefix from content and parsing arguments. So if you type `.faqadd This is a question? This is an answer`, the arguments will be `This` and `is a question? This is an answer`. If you want to prevent this, you can use quotation marks and the problem will be solved: `.faqadd "This is a question?" "This is an answer."`

Have a nice day.